# Error when writing a conditional query (ternary)

Tags: mysql, jasper-reports

I have two parameters $P{param1} and $P{param2}. The $P{param1} is the one that prompts when the query is being executed. The $P{param2} contains the conditional query that when $P{param1} is null, show all records, else choose the id that matches the parameter.

Here is my conditional query for $P{param2}:

```
$P{param1}.equals(" ") ? "SELECT * FROM tablerecords" : $P{param2}.equals($P{param1})
```

The problem is when I try to execute the query and ask for parameter1 and for example I put 2 (which is the id), The query says "The document has no pages" and when I try to put 1,2,3 the query returns ALL the records.

This is my sql query in the main report by the way:

```
SELECT
c.id,
p.lastname,
p.firstname
FROM person_tbl as p,code_tbl as c
WHERE $P!{param2}
AND p.id=c.id
ORDER BY 1;
```

The $P{param1} value is the id

Comment: what you want to achieve? as far as i see, " " is not equal to null, you should check like ($P{param1}==null || $P{param1}.toString().trim().length<=0)?"select * from tablerecords":$P{param1}

Comment: I tried this condition as well, ($P{param1}==null || $P{param1}.toString().trim().length<=0) as well but it seems to be not working. I get "The document has no pages" when it should output the SELECT query in the condition if NULL. @Arasu

Comment: the condition query is not the problem, your are missing something,  show your jrxml

Comment: i just paste the jrxml below. and i made some minimal changes to it. those were the actual fields. thanks @Arasu

Comment: btw you can add the jrxml in your question itself

Comment: You should not be giving a field value as the default value for a parameter.